# What is printed as a result of executing the following program / JAVA?

Tags: java

I have got a piece of Java code that I struggle to understand how the code works.

The most embarrassing thing about it is, I actually know what it prints out since I used Blue-J, and I did also de-bugging to understand how this code works,but I still didn't understand how the code works, if you understand it please explain it step-by-step, thanks in advance, anyway this is my code:

```
public class T13 {
    private static int s = 1;
    private int id;
    T13() {
        id = s;
        s++;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T13 t1 = new T13(); 
        System.out.println("t1: " + t1.id + ", " + t1.s);
        T13 t2 = new T13();
        System.out.println("t2: " + t2.id + ", " + t2.s);
    }
}
```

And it prints out following:

```
t1: 1, 2
t2: 2, 3
```

Comment: How do you think it works?

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: Probably the concept of `static` ....

Comment: Can you explain what you *do* understand?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I just understand following:                           private static int s = 1;// s is assigned to 1.
    private int id;// id is a private variable of int value
    T13() {
        id = s;// id gets the copy value of s
        s++;// s will e added 1.

Comment: Research what the keyword `static` means in the line `private static int s = 1;`

Comment: I thought the line private static int s = 1; means simply s assigned to 1 can be seen just by selected users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. T13 hold a static member s, which is first initialized with 1.

Static class variable are the one shared by all instances of the class. That is, each time you create a T13 instance variable (such in your code new T13()), the member s is the same memory location and shared by all T13.

A static initialization is performed only once by run, before any T13 instance is actually created.

As a consequence, before your first T13 t1 = new T13(), s is set to 1. Then you enter the creator, where is still 1, id set to s, so it's 1, ans s is incremented to 2.

The next new T13() find s to 2, id is set to 2, and s is incremented to 3. Hence your results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much, you are my hero.

Comment: I have got a question, in the step: t2.id variable t2 gets connected with variable id with a help of dot, does this sort of connection got a specific name? It is not concatenation, but maybe there is a name, then l would like to google it to find out more about it.

Comment: The purpose of the point is to get access to a specific member from the instance. The name of the dot in this context is 'class member selector'. Think of the class as an aggregation description. The class contains a collection of members. Once you got an instance out of the class, you access to any of the member by using the dot syntax.

Comment: thanks, l will am digesting this stuff right now, once i am confident i will try another example and if i will struggle again then l am gonna open up a separate thread about it and ask again for help :p

Answer (score 1):

### Never refer to static members with instance references

And now you know why, it can be confusing to anyone reading your code:

```
System.out.println("t1: " + t1.id + ", " + t1.s);
System.out.println("t2: " + t2.id + ", " + t2.s);
```

in both cases `t1.s` and `t2.s` are actuall references to `T13.s`
and thus the the same as:

```
System.out.println("t1: " + t1.id + ", " + T13.s);
```

This is because:

```
private static int s = 1;
```

belongs to the `Class` that every instance shares, there is only one `s` and it is shared by all instances of that are of type `T13` or inherit from `T13`.

#### `static` members should be used sparingly and `static final` is preferred

```
private static final AtomicInteger S = new AtomicInteger();
```

Would be the preferred implementation of a `Class` level counter. It is thread safe that way.
Also `static final` members are easier to reason about and are thread safe.

Then in your constructor you would do:

```
T13() { this.id = T13.S.getAndIncrement(); }
```

with no worries about concurrency issues

#### Java Style Guide Conventions

Java Style Guide conventions state that any `static final` members should be `ALL_UPPER_CASE` to help distinguish them from `instance` members.

```
private static final AtomicInteger S = new AtomicInteger(1);
private int id;
```

Would be the idiomatic way to name `static final` members. Doing this shows you know the Java conventions and helps make these special cases stand out in your code.

Comment: Only constants should be all uppercase if I'm not mistaken. So `s` shouldn't.

Comment: well I only do `static final` members ever so that isn't a problem.

Comment: The java code I simply copied and pasted was from past exam, and I wanted to find out how it works since I knew the value that prints out but didn't know how the code worked. User @Stéphane de Luca, already did a great job and explained exactly what I was looking for, but still thank you for your general info.